# Writing with a leftskip

Tags: indentation, typography

My aim is to write the body text and only the body with a big left skip; theorems, titles and display math starting from the very left, without skips.

I use the command `\leftskip=4cm`, which works good on the body ignoring all the environments, but works also for titles. I'm putting it into the preamble.

What do you suggest me?

Although LaTeX is the best in organizing text, I want it to write my personal notes and I absolutely need to use my personal typeset.

**EXAMPLES**

Here is an example of what I've done till now (I hope not-English examples are allowed, just for the sake of typesetting):
[image]

and here is an example of what I'd like to make:
[image]

Here is a minimal executible code:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage{geometry} %typography
    \usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

%   THEOREMS
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}   %theorems:  unindented environment
\newtheorem*{dimostratio}{Proof} 
\newenvironment{proof.} %proofs:    indented environment
    {\begin{dimostratio}  \leftskip=4.5cm   \mbox{} \noindent\ignorespaces  }
    {\end{dimostratio}}

%   TYPOGRAPHY 
    \geometry{a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm,  bindingoffset=5mm}
    \leftskip = 4.5cm           % indentation of everythingh isn't a theorem. 

%DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
    Here is the indented body.       %indented as I like.
    \lipsum[1]                  
\section{Indented (sic) title}       %indented but I don't like.
    \lipsum[2]
    
\begin{teo} Here is an unindented environment, as I like.
\end{teo}
\begin{proof.} 
    And here is an indented environment, as I like.
    \end{proof.}

    \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try putting \begin{trivlist} ... \end{trivlist} around anything you want to NOT be shifted.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... If possible can you post a reference image of your requirement for easy understanding...

Comment: @JohnKormylo thank you for the suggestion. It's a bit baroque but works and is very useful!

Comment: @MadyYuvi thank you for the welcome. Here you are images. :)

Comment: @Sebastiano no, it's not what I'm looking for. I'd like to write all my main text in mini-page, not only some sections (a bit exotic, I know). Thank the same for the solution.

Comment: @TizianoAndreaAmato Can you edit your question, please, with a minimal compilable code of your work? Your question it is not very clear or/duplicate.

Comment: @Sebastiano here you is =) thank you for your interest.
the matter is that I don't want to indent a whole paragraph, but all the text exept for titles and theorems. I want to have a standard indentation all over my writes.
Hoping the code is a good exempla, although without John Kormylo's useful trick.

Comment: @TizianoAndreaAmato Hi, improved your code if it possible. :-) Regards.